# when anchor tag replaced by <Link>, onKeyDown (accessibility) handlers lost/not working

Tags: react-router, anchor, accessibility

Replaced `<a>` with react-router `<Link/>`.  onClick and href (now 'to') work as expected.  onKeyDown is lost.  How to keep  'accessible' - ensure onKeyDown() works?

```
<a className='focusable'
   href={'/a/b/c'}
   onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
   onFocus={this.handleOnFocus}
   onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}
   ref={(ref) => {this.aref = ref;}}
   tabIndex='-1'
>
...
</a>

replaced by:

<Link className='focusable'
   to={'/a/b/c'}
   onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
   onFocus={this.handleOnFocus}
   onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}
   ref={(ref) => {this.aref = ref;}}
   tabIndex='-1'
>
...
</Link>
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: no, none (have warning related to other parts of the code)

Comment: are you sure that you press some key exactly when link is focused?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried an [ARIA role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques) for this? (I've linked to the less dry MDN version of the documentation)

Might look like this:

`<Link className='focusable'
   to={'/a/b/c'}
   onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
   onFocus={this.handleOnFocus}
   onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}
   ref={(ref) => {this.aref = ref;}}
   tabIndex='-1'
   role='link'
>
...
</Link>`

Worth a shot